# JPA BIT(n) mapping

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I have a Postgres table, with a `BIT(4)` column in it.
When creating the corresponding entity class, NetBeans generates a `Boolean` field for the column, which is of course invalid, since I can not store all 4 bit values in it.

What would be the correct mapping for the column?

Thank,
krisy

Comment: I don't know about the problem myself but https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=985798 is having a similar issue with extensive code and a solution. Maybe this is what you are lookiing for...

Comment: Yes, this is what I have been looking for, thanks!

Comment: I added it as an answer for other. Accept it if it got you to the solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*repost from my comment to make it an answer*

I don't know about the problem myself but http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=985798 is having a similar issue with extensive code and a solution. Maybe this is what you are looking for...